# How much damage do books do as weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage, improvised-weaponry

What would be the weapon stats be for books? I figure that the damage would be 1d4 for small books/1d6 for medium sized books & 1d8 for large sized books. I could be wrong though, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A book used as a weapon would use the normal rules for [improvised weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#improvisedWeapons). As the rule says, damage is based on judgement and comparing to existing weapons. (There are other details of course — best to read the rule to get the full picture.)

Since few books are large enough to compare to a longsword and still be light enough to use as a weapon (or even *as a book*), likely the most damage even a “large” book would do would be 1d4 — comparable to a club. Perhaps even 1d4 nonlethal (as a sap).

Answer (score 6):

In the **Complete Warrior** (page 159) there is a table which state the damage dice of improvised weapon by their weight.
I prefer this rule instead of comparing with existing weapon for anything that is made of unusual material (at least for weapon) or which don't really look like a weapon.

One of our small books, lightweight and paperback, should do 1d3 non lethal.
A big wizard spellbook, weighting 3 lbs. and hardcover, should do 1d4 lethal damage.