# Is it possible for books used as weapons to overcome damage reduction?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage, improvised-weaponry, damage-reduction

I want my character to use books as melee weapons. But I'm concerned about overcoming damage reduction.

Is it possible to make a book out of a special material such as cold iron, adamantine, or alchemical silver; or to modify an existing book to add a metal cover, such that it would overcome damage reduction when used as a weapon? How much damage reduction would the various material/book types do? If it helps my characters tend to be non-literal bookworms.naturally they would have a habit of using books as weapons.

Related: [How much damage do books do as weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89119/23970)

Comment: Just *what* in the world are you trying to accomplish with this?!

Comment: Is this a real problem you're facing with a character or situation in a game? If so, [edit]ing to tell us more about the character or the situation that involves making/using a book with special materials for combat purposes would improve the question. Explaining how you've tried and not succeeded to solve this problem by reading the rules would also help us understand the problem (and therefore improve the question).

Comment: @Miniman, based on a previous question by this same user my best guess is that he is trying to make a character that uses books as melee weapons and wants to know if it would be possible to overcome damage resistance based on the materials these books are made of.

Comment: @GreedyRadish you're quite correct.

Comment: @AbrahamRay, the trouble is that the question as it is currently worded doesn't make any of that clear. We aren't mind readers here. We need to know what your actual problem is before we can help you solve it. =)

Comment: Seems really clear to me the way it is worded - they want to use a book as a weapon in combat, and want to know if there is an existing rule to modify the book with special materials so that it will overcome damage resistance - where is the confusion?

Comment: Suggested an edit to the question. I also suggest that when your character is done, that you have the author of your book-weapons be Robert Jordan for laughs. ^^

Comment: @nijineko The question as-written seems quite clear, yes, but the answer self-written by the author doesn't answer the question that is written, indicating that what the question says is *not* what they meant to ask. Hence why this is closed (again) as unclear. (I would rewrite it to be the question their answer appears to be answering, except that previous comments have indicated that the question *does* say what they meant to ask, leading to contradiction. It's basically a complete mess and I'm not going to try to fix it anymore.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm going to delete my answer to help people along as my answer isn't very helpful anyway. I just deleted it now.

Comment: Your comments earlier indicated that you got the answer you were looking for already. However, this page is no longer helping anyone, and constant change is sucking up community attention to no good effect. I'm going to lock this for a while for the sake of letting the community move on, since there's no point in fiddling with this mess more when you've already got your answer anyway. When/if your question auto-block expires, you can take another stab at asking a different good, practical, clear question. We're just going to let this one lie for a while, and be a reminder how not to do it.

Comment: Gotcha--that makes more sense. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules only provide for adding these metals to weapons that are already made of metal.  Fortunately, Complete Arcane has costs for spellbooks with covers of "Metal, hard" and "Metal, soft" on page 140.  (Thanks to KRyan for the citation.)  If you're using one of these spellbooks as your weapon, you can then follow the [Special Materials rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm) as normal to get the price for masterwork, magic, silvered, adamantine, or cold iron spellbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I doubt a blacksmith would have the know how, or the experience to silver a book (however that would work), you could instead attempt to to rebind the book, using either a metal overlay or merely stud the book in the required material. This would satisfy both the gold cost, and the logical approach that the metal must contact the foe.
Example:

[image: A book bound in a metal cover]

Answer (score 0):

A book the size of a spelllbook could conceivably be considered a small improvised weapon. I've ruled this in the past to be a 1d3 weapon for a full spellbook, or a 1d2 for a traveling spellbook. Additionally, since the book isn't designed for this kind of treatment, doing so deals the book 1d3 damage each time it hits.

As to special materials... this I haven't encountered, not like you're describing. If I had to make a ruling, though? I've always had a house ruling that cold iron is anathema to magic, thus you can't make a spellbook out of it. No reason silversheen wouldn't work, though. Likewise, actually making the book out of silver would make it heavier and cost a lot, but would give it the alchemical silver traits. Again, though, these are house rulings, so YMMV.